How can I get a useful "W1036 Variable might not have been initialized" warning
var
  aClass: TTestClass;
begin
  try
    aClass:= TTestClass.Create;
    // Do something
  finally
    if aClass <> nil then aClass.Free;
  end;
end;

This will raise the W1036, but there is a check to make this as memory-safe as possible. How can I make the compiler see the safety of this so it doesn't fire hundreds of warnings across the project ? This makes the warnings list basically useless because the useful ones get buried under hundreds like these.
Doing aClass := nil;, weirdly enough satisfies the compiler. I guess the only thing it's doing is looking for a direct assignment in its scope ?
Thanks !

The if aClass <> nil then part is superfluous as Free already checks for nil.

@UliGerhardt Ah, very cool, it does indeed !

Just to make it 100% clear: The warning issued here is a very correct and valuable one, since the code has a serious bug. If the TTestClass.Create constructor raises an exception (which is idiomatic and not at all uncommon), the partly-created object's destructor will automatically run, but the execution in your code will stop, so nothing is assigned to aClass. Since aClass is a local variable of an unmanaged type, it is not initialised, so its initial value is "random" (whatever happens to be there in your computer's RAM). And since you are inside a try..finally block, this will...

...run your finally block, so you will call aClass.Free on a random memory address aClass. Then anything can happen. If you are lucky, you get an AV. But it is also possible that your app will send a 6.23E52 USD invoice the next week instead of the expected 20 USD invoice. Then someone will not be happy. So you always write LFrog := TFrog.Create; try { use LFrog } finally LFrog.Free end and never try LFrog := TFrog.Create; { use LFrog } finally LFrog.Free; end. I think I have given that example hundreds of times the last few decades; it's really super important.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110021/delphi-raise-exception-in-constructor etc.

The close as a duplicate is fine because the question you are asking is based on a false premise. You are asking how to correct compiler behaviour that you think is wrong. However, the compiler is correct, and your code is wrong.

Answering this question
An exception can be raised by TTestClass.Create, before the assignment to aClass has happened, and then the finally clause is executed, with aClass still not initialized. So the warning is actually true.
Adding aClass := nil at the beginning makes sure that aClass is always initialized when the line using it in the finally clause is reached.
Two typical try-finally patterns
The more typical pattern, however, is to put the assignment aClass := TTestClass.Create line before try. This makes sense, because try-finally is meaningful only after aClass has been assigned.
The alternative with assigning aClass := nil first is more common when there are two or more variables that need to be guarded. Then assigning nil first might give nicer-looking code than a nested try-finally construct (but this is already more a matter of taste).
So both of these resource-protection patterns are good:
Pattern 1
A := TSomeClass.Create;
try
  B := TSomeClass.Create;
  try
    // ... Do something ...
  finally
    B.Free;
  end;
finally
  A.Free;
end;

Pattern 2
A := nil;
B := nil;
try
  A := TSomeClass.Create;
  B := TSomeClass.Create;
  // ... Do something ...
finally
  A.Free;
  B.Free;
end;


The warning is technically true yes, but in these kind of cases not useful at all. I was hoping the static analysis engine was more intelligent and that I just didn't know how to properly communicate with it...

It's not just technically true, it is very real. The constructor (TTestClass.Create) has a real chance/risk of failing, raising an exception, in which case the code would continue to run in the finally clause, with aClass still uninitialized, pointing to whatever (probably non-nil) random memory it happened to be pointing at from the beginning. Ah, this should be mentioned - it might not be obvious - that local variables are not initialized to anything in Delphi. (As opposed to global variables and class fields, which are guaranteed to be automatically initialized to nil/zero/empty string.)

Also worth mentioning: all destructors should always be written in a way that can handle half-initialized objects. I.e. exactly for the case where the constructor fails/raises an exception. Luckily, class fields are guaranteed to be automatically initialized to nil, and FSomething.Free works (=does nothing) even if FSomething is nil, so in practice, this is not hard.

Okay ; is there some way of initializing local variables in the same way that class fields are ? Seems strange to have one and not the other ? The only difference is that one live son the heap, but if the process exists for one then it must be applicable to the stack as well ? Is it just a backwards-compatibility thing ?

I'm not sure of the "why" and I agree that it doesn't look logical. The only way of initializing local variables is to simply initialize them oneself, one by one, with a plain ordinary assignment.

If that's true then it's just sad. From my POV it seems rather simple to let people include a compiler flag for example, that triggers the code to initialize the local variables. Is there an external tool developed by the community to achieve this perhaps ? Although if you're reduced to this I suppose it's less costly to simply move to a better language.

@JohnJohn, Delphi does not initialize local variables, this is documented: Local variables cannot be initialized in their declarations. Multiple variable declarations (such as var X, Y, Z: Real;) cannot include initializations, nor can declarations of variant and file-type variables.
If you do not explicitly initialize a global variable, the compiler initializes it to 0. Object instance data (fields) are also initialized to 0. The contents of a local variable are undefined until a value is assigned to them.

@whosrdaddy yes, this was already said just above ?

@JohnJohn, From memory, Embarcadero has said (in response to an enhancement request) that they don't want to change that long-standing convention, as it would add overhead that some customers would complain about.  The requester also suggested that it be a compiler flag, but they didn't answer that bit.  Again, that's just from my memory. Don't quote me on it!

I guess it could be fragile, in an imagined future where a compiler flag has been introduced, to write code that relies upon a compiler flag and local variables being initialized. So it might perhaps be best to leave it as it is - and just repeat the knowledge that local variables are not initialized. It's rarely a real problem, and the compiler warning helps.

"It could be fragile" is not a sufficient argument imo. We're never having any improvements ever if "it could be fragile". Delphi already uses tons of compiler flags, notably to handle deprecations and platform targeting.
Introduce a $LOCALVARSINIT flag and a warning that says it's off in this or that unit. Now you have an opt-in solution for those who want it.

I definitely don't want local cars initialized by default because that would be a waste of time.

@JohnJohn: I agree with the others that a compiler option to enable/disable default zero initialisation of (non-managed) local variables is not a great idea (for example, because people copy and paste code -- this is like begging for strange and random bugs, almost completely unnecessarily). If you want all your local variables to be initialised, you can do that yourself with inline variable declarations: var x := 0; var Match := False; var b := TBitmap(nil);.

@AndreasRejbrand I don't know where you got the idea from but that is not valid Delphi code

@JohnJohn: Yes, that is very much valid Delphi code. I write code like this every day, both at work and at home! But please pay attention to the part where I say "inline variable declarations". This syntax was introduced in Delphi 10.3. (Wasn't it even you that asked a few weeks ago when inline variable declarations were first introduced?)

Oh okay I copy-pasted your code but it wasn't actually declaring the variables, just the values. But by god why make an update allowing """"inline"""" declarations that are just moving the declarations to the var body instead of the function body ? Useless...
